# I am trying to create a program that converts bytes to human readable JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that converts bytes to human readable. Unfortunately, I keep getting an error when I try to format the values to 2 decimal figures.

```
public class Challenge                                                      
{                                                       

    public static String formatAsMemory(long size) {
       long limit = 10 * 1024;
       long limit2 = limit * 2 - 1;
        if(size < 0) {
        size = Math.abs(size);
    }

    if(size <=1023) {
        return String.format("%s%.2f bytes",size);
    } else {
        size = Math.round((double) size / 1024);
        if (size < limit2) {
            return String.format("%s%.2f Kb",size);
        } else {
            size = Math.round((double)size / 1024);
            if (size < limit2) {
                return String.format("%s%.2f Mb",size);
            } else {
                size = Math.round((double)size / 1024);
                if (size < limit2) {
                    return String.format("%s%.2f Gb",size);
                } else {
                    size = Math.round((double)size / 1024);
                        return String.format("%s%.2f Tb",size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

The error I'm receiving:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.2f' at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source) at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source) at Challenge.formatAsMemory(Challenge.java:12) at Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: size is a `long` not a floating point number.

Comment: @nldoty Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingFormatArgumentException: Format specifier '%.2f'
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
 at Challenge.formatAsMemory(Challenge.java:12)
 at Main.main(Main.java:5)

Comment: cast as float `return String.format("%.2f bytes", (float)size);`

Comment: What's with the extra `%s`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your return statement `return String.format("%s%.2f bytes",size);` 
This is requesting two arguments: `%s`, which is any type to String, and `%f`, which is a floating point to decimal number. You're supplying too few arguments. If you intend to just use `size` remember that it is a long, not a float.